# View's height relative to other view's height in FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

How to make `View's` height relative to other view in the same `FrameLayout`?

Is it possible to use only xml?

In short: I want `ImageView's` height(green) equal to `ImageView's` height(purple) + `TextView's` height(black)

[image: Visualize]

**Edit:** xml included

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#61B329"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            />
        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:background="#77896C"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

            android:background="#3F602B"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_voice_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="#7D26CD"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:text="TEST"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Edit2:** set `layout_height` to `match_parent` follow @L-X's comment is work but the background is higher if add src to background `ImageViews`

[image]

Comment: can you provide your xml file?

Comment: In your First Linear layout make its layout_height to match_parent , this will make your Green Image height equals to Purple ImageView +TextView height ,